# Stacknavigator not navigating to new screen while using functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's my `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';

import Reducers from './app/reducers';

import Preload from './app/Screens/Preload';
import HomeScreen from './app/Screens/HomeScreen';

let store = createStore(
  Reducers,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen, navigationOptions: {header: null }},
  Preload: {screen: Preload, navigationOptions: {header: null }},
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AppContainer/>
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

`HomeScreen.js` has a nested `Wrap.js` component which in turn has a `Header.js` component where the `onPress` event is handled to load a new screen, in this case the `Preload.js` screen.

When I press the TouchableOpacity component, there is no error thrown but nothing happens either. The new screen doesn't load. Please let me know how to load new screens while using functional components.

Here are the respective components mentioned above.

`Wrap.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Platform, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import Colors from '../../Constants/Colors'
import Header from './Header'

const Wrap = (props) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainWrapper}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Header />
        {props.children}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    height: "100%",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0

  }
})

export default Wrap
```

`Header.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import SourceImages from '../../Constants/SourceImages'
import Colors from '../../Constants/Colors'
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const {navigate} = NavigationActions;

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <View style={styles.menuIconWrapper}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconWrapper}
          onPress={()=>{navigate('Preload')}}

        >
          <FontAwesome name="navicon" style={styles.icon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.logoWrapper}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={ SourceImages.logo } resizeMode="contain" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.cartIconWrapper}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconWrapper} >
          <FontAwesome name="shopping-basket" style={styles.icon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}


export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in following way:

1- import { withNavigation } from  'react-navigation' instead of   NavigationActions

2- use const Header = (props) instead of const Header = ()

3- use props.navigation instead of const {navigate} = NavigationActions;

4- export default withNavigation(Header) instead of export default Header

It will work this way:

```
import { withNavigation } from  'react-navigation'


const Header = (props)


props.navigation.navigate('Preload')


export default withNavigation(Header)
```

Comment: I am getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined`

Comment: use const Header = (props) instead of const Header = () and also include props in <Header />

Comment: The error above is  after I have passed in the props to header component. Without it it would give another error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined`

Comment: try to console.log(props) and see what you get

Comment: I've logged out at each component and found that, at the HomeScreen component which is at the top, the navigator is available in the props. In the wrapper and header though when I log out the props, it says [Object, Object].

Comment: Thank you, thank you, so much. You forgot to include that the exported child component should be wrapped in the `withNavigation`. It works once that is done. Please add that to your answer so others can benefit if you don't mind.

`export default withNavigation(Header)`